# Connecting to a Remote Cloudera Spark Cluster using Sparklyr with the method Livy

Tags: r, sparklyr, livy

Not able to connect to a Remote spark cluster using Sparklyr Livy Method.

```
config <- livy_config(username="<username>", password="<password>")
sc <- spark_connect(master = "<address>", method = "livy", config = config)
```

I am getting an error:

> Error in value[3L] :    Failed to initialize livy connection:
>   Unable to retrieve a spark_connection from object of class function

Livy server is started on the cluster. Other Livy commands are working fine.
Remote cluster is a cloudera managed cluster.

The problem resolved when the sparklyr was reinstalled from CRAN, earlier the sparlyr was installed from using devtools::install_github("rstudio/sparklyr")